How can I perform UI actions on Non-UI Threads / How to continue UI updates even when app is in background on Android and Meta Quest (for VR)
I am working on Meta Quest, which is essentially an Android device. It supports running both 2D and VR applications. When a VR application is running, other 2D applications go into the background. When the game is sent to the background, it gets paused, causing Unity to stop its main loop, which includes calling Update, FixedUpdate, animations, etc. However, it is still possible to run custom threads during this time.
Many Unity features are accessible only on the main thread, and attempting to use them from another thread results in failure. I've tried various methods to queue my calls, but they all fail since the main thread doesn't execute them later.
My challenge is that I need my application to run when another VR game is active, even if it is technically in the background. However, the script must operate on the main thread as it utilizes Unity objects and animations, which only run on the main thread. The application does not need to be visible.
So in simple terms I want to perform UI actions on a non UI thread on android or when the app is still in the background,
At this point I don't really need code I just need an explanation or maybe a link to an article or someone who has tried this to help out all I need is to outline the steps or procedures I need to take for me to achieve this. Your help will be very much appreciated.
I've tried various methods to queue my calls, but they all fail since the main thread doesn't execute them later.
I am just looking for a possible or ideal list of steps to take to get this done.

Yes, this is possible using a background service class and listening for this service in Unity using C#. It has some downsides though, in C# code you will have to implement battery optimization code otherwise the system will always kill your program.
You may also have to use the IL2CPP code generation option in your Android player settings in Unity as it helps with speed, but just be prepared for long build time.
public class BackgroundServicePlugin extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "BackgroundServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getClass());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Game Running in Background")
            .setContentText("Tap to return to the game")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    }

    public static void startForegroundService() {
        Context context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundServicePlugin.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    public static void stopForegroundService() {
        Context context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundServicePlugin.class);
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}

